# How do I let multiple commands run at the same time in python?

Tags: python

Basically, I was curious as to how I can crash any computer. I know, Cheap low hanging fruit but I was curious and I am good at python so I didn't care much. I wanted to learn. So my idea was, opening multiple scrips or the same script together which would open something else heavy in a loop.
So something like:

```
import os
while 1==1:
    os.system('python3 otherscript1.py')
```

Comment: You can keep spawning infinitely-running new processes until system resources are completely exhausted.

Comment: Tip: `while True:` tends to be clearer.

Comment: You can put each command in the background (assuming *nix): `os.sytem('python3 otherscript1.py &')`. That should cause problems quickly enough.

Comment: If you want to crash your system in similar ways, have a look at [fork bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

Comment: Thank you so much guys. It helped a lot. It solved a lot of other queries that I had.